# Postman Error [err_http_headers_sent]: cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Using ReactJS & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postman

[[err_http_headers_sent]: cannot set headers after they are sent to the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0BQc.png)
<=(Link is picture of the actual error)

I have been stuck on this issue for two weeks and the other Stack Overflow posts with this issue don't seem to resolve the issue.  Hoping someone can help with what will resolve this issue. I am using ReactJS and NodeJS "express" for the backend.  I get this error when testing in Postman.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

server.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
import { routes } from '../routes/index';
import { initializeDbConnection } from './db';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
//This allows access the body of POST/PUT requests in our route handlers as req.body
app.use(express.json());
//Add all the routes to Express server exported from routes/index.js
routes.forEach(route => {
     app[route.method](route.path, route.handler);
});
// Connect to the database, then start the server.
// This prevents from having to create a new DB
// connection for every request
initializeDbConnection()
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
        });
    });
```

signuproute.js code

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { getDbConnection } from '../src/db';
export const signUpRoute = {
    path: '/api/signup',
    method: 'post',
    handler: async (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const db = getDbConnection('react-auth-db');
        const user = await db.collection('users').findOne({ email });
        if (user) {
            res.sendStatus(409);
        }
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        //change once you figure out what info you want to store from users
        const startingInfo = {
            hairColor: '',
            favoriteFood: '',
            bio: '',
        };
        const result = await db.collection('users').insertOne({
            email,
            passwordHash,
            info: startingInfo,
            isVerified: false,
        });
        const { insertedId } = result;
        jwt.sign({
            id: insertedId,
            email,
            info: startingInfo,
            isVerified: false,
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {
            expiresIn: '2d',
        },
        (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.status(200).send({ token });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add return on your res

```
return res.sendStatus(409);
```

and

```
return res.status(200).send({ token });
```